# What's the max number of documents I should be fetching from a given Firestore query?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with a real time chat app that can have hundreds of users in the same chat at the same time. My question is in regards to fetching the users' profiles from Firestore, and if there's a limit to the number of documents I should be fetching in a single call? I allow my users to preview how many people are present in a given chat, and so in order to do this I typically have to fetch all of the documents in my collection of users.

Answer (score 1):

I typically recommend not retrieving more information than fits on a single screen/view within your app. Limiting yourself to a 'screenful' (or a few screenfuls) of information, ensures you neither rack up your database bill, nor your user's bandwidth bill needlessly.

If you have a use-case where you need to show a count, consider storing that actual count in the database. If you have to read a lot of documents to count them, you're wasting both your own money, and the user's bandwidth again. That's why the most common approach is to store a counter in the database, and then update with every write operation, and read only the counter if you need to display a count. There's even an example of this in the [Firestore documentation on distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).